# Return the second level directory names only

Tags: powershell, directory, powershell-4.0

I would like to retrieve all (and only) second level directory names of my disk. For example, `C:\folder1\folder2` and `C:\folder1\folder3`, I need to retrieve only `folder2` and `folder3`.

I write this and the PS displays all the directory names:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer} | Select-Object Name
```

I found this [help](https://superuser.com/questions/825874/using-get-childitem-but-only-look-at-the-2nd-level-down), and I modify the previous command in this way:

```
 Get-ChildItem -Recurse |  `Where-Object {($_.directory -match '^*\\\S*$')} ` | ForEach-Object {?{ $_.PSIsContainer} | Select-Object Name }
```

but when I use it the PS doesn't display anything.

I can't understand why, someone can help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only files appear to have a `.directory` property, directories do not, so you will never get something which passes your (`.directory` matches a pattern) filter and also passes your (`PSIsContainer`) filter.

Except that your `PSIsContainer` filter doesn't work:

```
| ForEach-Object {?{ $_.PSIsContainer} | Select-Object Name }
```

this doesn't make sense; you can only filter the pipeline using `?` with `cmdlet | ? {}`, you cannot filter at the start of a loop scriptblock with no input and get anything useful. This is running `where-object {}` over and over in a loop,  - and that has no output.

Using -Recurse will be very slow, as you go into every single directory all the way to the end, and make [fileinfo] objects for all the files as well.

Apart from Matt's wildcard answer, assuming PS v3 or above, you could list all the directories in the root, and then all the directories inside those, and stop there:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\ -Directory | Get-ChildItem -Directory | Select -ExpandProperty Name

or

gci c:\ -Dir | ForEach { (gci $_ -Dir).Name }
```

Comment: Hello! I tried with `-Directory` and it works. Thank you for yr help! Actually, I also tried to use `ForEach-Object {?{ $_.PSIsContainer} | Select-Object Name` after the `-Directory` statement and it works. Obviously `Select Name` is better. But... just to let you know. Thank you!

Comment: @Hari It works? I try `gci | foreach { ? { $_.PsIsContainer } } ` and there is no output - no files, no folders. the `$_` has no value ... ?

Comment: I tried this command: `Get-ChildItem C:\*\* -Directory | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer} | Select -ExpandProperty Name` and it gaves me the same output of yours: `Get-ChildItem c:\ -Directory | Get-ChildItem -Directory | Select -ExpandProperty Name`. So... yes it works.

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to use some fun wildcards to get what you want here.

```
Get-ChildItem \*\*\ | Where-Object{$_.PSIsContainer}
```

Or if you have at least PowerShell 3.0 this would be faster

```
Get-ChildItem \*\*\ -Directory
```

Then if you wanted just the names tack on `| Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name`

Answer (score 0):

Here with full path, network compatible:

```
(Get-ChildItem "\\folder1\" -Dir).fullname | ForEach {(Get-ChildItem $_ -Dir).name}
```

Want it stored in an array?

```
$subfolders = (Get-ChildItem "\\folder1\" -Dir).fullname | ForEach {(Get-ChildItem $_ -Dir).name}
```